# Obfuscated NuGet Packages and Deployment considerations

Tags: .net, nuget, obfuscation

This has been a major confusion and a consideration for deployment.

I have a portable class library (that targets Mono and Xamarin platforms) and it has a dependency licensing library as well. In order to protect tampering of the licensing library I am considering to get it obfuscated.

My question here is:

If a **NuGet** library is obfuscated, will it cause trouble for other projects referencing the library. Say for instance in *Windows Store apps* or even Android apps? Will their app be rejected from these stores due to the usage of an obfuscated library?

I have heard that obfuscated libraries may add **pdb** packages as a workaround. Will that suffice?

Any input or suggestion on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you develop a library, and obfuscate it private part (not a visible interface, that people use to communicate with your library) I don't see a problem for other developers to use your library.

You can submit an application with the obfuscated library to Windows/Andorid stores. They indeed scan your code, but did that in a more intelligent way (in assembler calls level, rather than plain code)

Comment: Thank you adding that. That should clear things up bit.